# Multiconfiguration USB Device - Problems in Catalina

Tags: macos, usb, macos-catalina, iokit, kernel-extension

The drivers for the interfaces of   USB device with 2nd configuration are getting KIOServiceTerminated . The same drivers for similar interfaces in configuration 1 are loading and working properly. I get the following log for the interface that is geting loaded and immediately getting Terminate message after these messages. What is the problem?

```
default 16:42:40.813546+0530    kernel  IOUSBHostInterface: not registry member at registerService()
default 16:42:40.813560+0530    kernel  IOUSBHostInterface: bad busy count (0,-1)


Backtrace 0xffffff8000a125c6 0xffffff7f812f4731 0xffffff7f812f38a1 0xffffff7f81129388 0xffffff800037b625 0xffffff800037b151 0xffffff80002e013e

default 16:42:40.813561+0530    kernel        Kernel Extensions in backtrace:

default 16:42:40.813570+0530    kernel           com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[5E8D1616-2C4B-3E81-B199-59D3531E0759]@0xffffff7f8111a000->0xffffff7f81212fff

default 16:42:40.813577+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController(1.0)[5F8013C3-D135-3795-8C05-F5DDA387ADC4]@0xffffff7f81100000

default 16:42:40.813584+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[98454AB6-B806-330F-98C6-FEA7F44D22BA]@0xffffff7f81108000

default 16:42:40.813590+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties(1.2)[A7569701-C592-31CF-8740-439114078F9F]@0xffffff7f81116000

default 16:42:40.813597+0530    kernel           com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(900.4.2)[3FCD6CD5-5077-374F-AD7A-6A0EA61E1FC5]@0xffffff7f812a2000->0xffffff7f8133bfff

default 16:42:40.813602+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f810a2000

default 16:42:40.813608+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[5E8D1616-2C4B-3E81-B199-59D3531E0759]@0xffffff7f8111a000

default 16:42:40.813615+0530    kernel              dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[98454AB6-B806-330F-98C6-FEA7F44D22BA]@0xffffff7f81108000
```

**cdc usb device info-list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>xxandroid_usbbus</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>5.5, xx Mobile USB CDC driver for MAV</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xx.driver.xxAndroidusbbus</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>USB CDC driver</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AndroidUSBCDCDevice</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xx.driver.xxAndroidusbbus</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>xxUSBCDC</string>
            <key>IOProbeScore</key>
            <integer>99999</integer>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
            <key>bDeviceClass</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>bDeviceProtocol</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>bDeviceSubClass</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily</key>
        <string>650.4.1</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.unsupported</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**acm cdc control interface plist info**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>xxandroid_mdmcontrol</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>5.5, xx Mobile USB CDC ACM driver Control Interface for MAV</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xx.driver.xxAndroidmdmcontrol</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>xxUSBCDCACMControl</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AndroidUSBCDCACMControl </key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xxxdriver.xxAndroidmdmcontrol</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>xxUSBCDCACMControl</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>IOProbeScore</key>
            <integer>99999</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceSubClass</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceProtocol</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily</key>
        <string>10.0.7</string>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily</key>
        <string>650.4.1</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.unsupported</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**acm data interface plist info**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>xxandroid_mdmcontrol</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>5.5, xx Mobile USB CDC ACM driver Control Interface for MAV</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xx.driver.xxAndroidmdmcontrol</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>xxUSBCDCACMControl</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AndroidUSBCDCACMControl </key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xxxdriver.xxAndroidmdmcontrol</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>xxUSBCDCACMControl</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>IOProbeScore</key>
            <integer>99999</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceSubClass</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceProtocol</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily</key>
        <string>10.0.7</string>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily</key>
        <string>650.4.1</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.unsupported</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**cdc serial interface plist info**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>5.5, xx Mobile USB CDC DIAG driver Interface for MAV</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>xxandroid_serial</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.xxx.driver.xxAndroidserial</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>xxUSBCDCSerialData</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>5.5</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AndroidUSBCDCSerail</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.xx.driver.xxAndroidserial</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>xxUSBCDCSerialData</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
            <key>InputBuffers</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>OutputBuffers</key>
            <integer>32</integer>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>1000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily</key>
        <string>10.0.7</string>
        <key>com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily</key>
        <string>650.4.1</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.bsd</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.mach</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
        <key>com.apple.kpi.unsupported</key>
        <string>13.0.0</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostInterface**

```
-o MTP@0  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBInterface, id 0x100002520, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (16 ms), retain 6>
    {
      "USBSpeed" = 3
      "iInterface" = 5
      "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294976802
      "bInterfaceProtocol" = 0
      "bAlternateSetting" = 0
      "idProduct" = 1000
      "bcdDevice" = 1028
      "USB Interface Name" = "MTP"
      "USB Product Name" = “xxx”
      "locationID" = 336592896
      "bInterfaceClass" = 255
      "bInterfaceSubClass" = 255
      "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBHostFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
      "USBPortType" = 0
      "kUSBString" = "MTP"
      "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
      "bConfigurationValue" = 1
      "USB Vendor Name" = “xxx”
      "idVendor" = 1000
      "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb"))
      "bNumEndpoints" = 3
      "USB Serial Number" = “xxxxx”
      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    }


+-o ADB Interface@1  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOUSBNub:IOUSBInterface, id 0x100002521, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (16 ms), retain 6>
    {
      "USBSpeed" = 3
      "iInterface" = 6
      "IOServiceLegacyMatchingRegistryID" = 4294976805
      "bInterfaceProtocol" = 1
      "bAlternateSetting" = 0
      "idProduct" = 1000
      "bcdDevice" = 1028
      "USB Interface Name" = "ADB Interface"
      "USB Product Name" = “xxxx”
      "locationID" = 336592896
      "bInterfaceClass" = 255
      "bInterfaceSubClass" = 66
      "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBHostFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
      "USBPortType" = 0
      "kUSBString" = "ADB Interface"
      "bInterfaceNumber" = 1
      "bConfigurationValue" = 1
      "USB Vendor Name" = “xxx”
      "idVendor" = 1000
      "IOServiceDEXTEntitlements" = (("com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb"))
      "bNumEndpoints" = 2
      "USB Serial Number" = “xxxx”
      "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
      "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    }
```

Comment: What kind of driver is this? Kext (IOUSBFamily or IOUSBHostFamily?), DriverKit, or IOKitLib? What exactly triggers this message? The implication is that this problem is specific to Catalina? Does that mean it works on <= Mojave?

Comment: @pmdj thanks for edit, this device is composite USB device(Android Mobile), having multiple interfaces (BUS,ACM,SERIAL). when I connect device drivers are loaded and this message appears. Before Catalina OS its working properly with same drivers and device, in catalina OS problem came. Bus driver (IOKitPersonalities -> IOProviderClass(IOUSBDevice) ), (OSBundleLibraries -> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily).  ACM Control Driver (IOKitPersonalities -> IOProviderClass(IOUSBInterface) ), (OSBundleLibraries -> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily,com.apple.iokit.IOUSBSerialFamily).

Comment: ACM Data Driver (IOKitPersonalities -> IOProviderClass(IOUSBInterface) ), (OSBundleLibraries -> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily,com.apple.iokit.IOUSBSerialFamily).      CDC Serial Driver (IOKitPersonalities -> IOProviderClass(IOUSBInterface) ), (OSBundleLibraries -> com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily,com.apple.iokit.IOUSBSerialFamily).

Comment: To clarify, are these codeless kexts that you control? (Perhaps you could edit your answer to include the IOKitPersonalities XML and/or the relevant part of the output from `ioreg -lirc IOUSBHostInterface`)

Comment: these are not codeless kexts, vendor specific USB interfaces similar to ACM/ECM.

Comment: OK, so the driver for these that you are trying to load is a full kext (with a binary)?

Comment: yes, device with same interfaces in configuration one works fine, but in another device with same interfaces in configuration 2 i get these issues, in all other previous OS its works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do at this point yet (you have provided very little hard information), so I'd ideally need some more information to be certain - kext info.plist, the API calls that are triggering the error, etc.

However, considering you list "IOProviderClass(IOUSBInterface)" in your comments and `com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily` shows up in the backtrace you quoted, my suspicion is that you are running into bugs in the increasingly badly maintained `IOUSBFamily` legacy compatibility layer you seem to be using in your kext. I have found various problems with this layer in Mojave and even more so in Catalina, some of them hardware-dependent (e.g. some problems only occur on some Mac models).

You can try reporting the bugs to Apple, but I suspect you will get the same advice I am about to give you: you should port your driver to the newer `IOUSBHostFamily` API. If possible, using DriverKit or as a regular user space daemon, otherwise as a kernel extension. If it must be a kernel extension, the `IOUSBHost*.h` header files from the macOS SDK contain porting instructions in the comments at the top of each file.

Comment: Thanks for reply,i will update info plist and ioreg output for the device. As WWDC update kexts are supported on catalina OS, so we are trying check in catalina OS. Do you have idea why this issue can happen? for USB acm data interface start is called after some time                                                    
default 20:15:47.424654+0530 kernel CDC ACM Data: not registry member at registerService()
default 20:15:47.424699+0530 kernel CDC ACM Data: bad busy count (0,-1)

Comment: @david Kexts are still supported on Catalina, yes. Based on the information you provided, it seems that you are using the IOUSBFamily API (`IOUSBInterface`, `IOUSBDevice`, etc.) in your kext. This was replaced with the IOUSBHostFamily API in macOS 10.11 El Capitan. The IOUSBFamily API was deprecated for some versions, and has since been completely removed from the macOS SDK. There is still a compatibility layer which translates IOUSBFamily calls to IOUSBHostFamily, but with every macOS version, new regressions seem to be introduced in this, causing problems with drivers that use the old API.

Comment: @david As Apple is gradually trying to remove 3rd party kexts, my suggestion is that if you are porting your kext to the new API, check if you can implement it via a DriverKit or user space driver instead, as these give a much better user experience on Catalina. (kexts require complicated user approval) DriverKit currently does not support a wide range of APIs, but USB is supported.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have updated plist and ioreg output.  if it helps you @pmdj kindly please let me know. meanwhile will go through your updates on latest mac releases. since kexts are supported in catalina OS we thought of fixing this. And we planned to move on in future OS for dexts. Thats the reason we are trying to load kexts on catalina.

Comment: @david Thanks for posting that additional information. It confirms you are definitely using the the old IOUSBFamily APIs. You may be able to work around the problem by changing your code - for example, it's possible you have a reference counting bug in your device reconfiguration code. However, it's equally possible that you're encountering a bug in Apple's API compatibility layer. My recommendation is to move away from IOUSBFamily, at least in the driver which sets the device's configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much pmdj. will check and let you know.